# TAB key is not working on NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Hi I used to use Eclipse as my IDE for java. I am starting using NetBeans now. 
I used TAB key to get out of parentheses or brackets in Eclipse. Which key do I need to use for NetBeans? I don't want to use an arrow key to pass parentheses or brackets.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use the **ENTER** key

Comment: This was the correct answer for me, though in my case I have to press enter twice for it to go out of the brackets.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution:

1. Go to Tools-->Options-->KeyMap
2. Inside the keyMap tab there is seach field type the following inside the box:

   Insertion Point to Next Word
3. Then in the shortcut field double click to edit the value
4. Finally you can put any key you want including the TAB key!

Note: It is recommended to use a combination of a hot key like SHIFT or CTRL with another key to avoid the overwriting that may occur.

Answer (score 0):

For that situation, perhaps if you are here--

```
System.out.println("Hello world."!);
```

once your cursor is where the "!" is, you can press ";" and netbeans will put it at the end of the line.. usually works for any grouping symbols (with the exception of double quotes).